# C - Duplication of Printf when an array is involved

Tags: c

I hope this isn't too basic of a question for stack overflow. But I have a query which is trying to determine the amount of grades in an array, and then ask for user input of each of those grades. It looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main (void)
{
int size;

printf ("Enter The Amount Of Grades In Your Array: ");
scanf("%i", &size);/*Stores Amount Of Grades In The Array*/

char myGrades[size];
int i;

for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
  {
  printf ("Enter the grade:");
  scanf ("%c",&myGrades[i]);
  }

return 0; 
}
```

I expect the first line after int i to read `"Enter The Grade:"` but instead it looks like `"Enter The Grade:""Enter The Grade:"`

I don't understand why it says enter the grade the second time without first asking for my input on the first "enter the grade". Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you should check that `size` holds a reasonable value. If the user puts in a big number the program will crash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first `scanf` is leaving the `\n` behind, and then automatically reading it again the next time as if you'd pressed enter (so the newline is stored in your array). You can get around this by using `" %c"` instead. The space will get rid of any newlines or spaces before the character you want.